# What is causing the Argentinian inflation?

Tags: inflation, argentina

What is causing the high rate of inflation which has been going on in Argentina for the past five years and appears to be getting worse?  I've read the country took out loans that they can not pay back.

Answer (score 1):

Large inflation rates of this magnitude are always cause by excessive money supply. All else are just minor details. See for example [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MYAGM2ARM189N#0).

Argentina unfortunately has not managed it's finances for decades and since the 1950s, Argentina has been in a recession more than any other major nation. The Nobel prize-winning economist Simon Kuznets remarked that there were four types of countries: the developed, the underdeveloped, Japan, and Argentina.